# AWS EC2 instance create via Ansible IAM Roles instance_profile_name UnauthorizedOperation: Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, ansible

I am trying to create EC2 instance via ansible using IAM roles but I while launching new instance I get error

```
failed: [localhost] => (item= IAMRole-1) => {"failed": true, "item": " IAMRole-1"}
msg: Instance creation failed => UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform
this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: Ckcjt2GD81D5dlF6XakTSDypnwrgeQb0k
ouRMKh3Ol1jue553EZ7OXPt6fk1Q1-4HM-tLNPCkiX7ZgJWXYGSjHg2xP1A9LR7KBiXYeCtFKEQIC
W9cot3KAKPVcNXkHLrhREMfiT5KYEtrsA2A-xFCdvqwM2hNTNf7Y6VGe0Z48EDIyO5p5DxdNFsaSChUcb
iRUhSyRXIGWr_ZKkGM9GoyoVWCBk3Ni2Td7zkZ1EfAIeRJobiOnYXKE6Q
```

whereas iam role has full ec2 access, with following policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "autoscaling:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 15):

The problem here is not with the [IAM Role for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) itself, rather that you (i.e. the AWS credentials you are using yourself) seem to lack the `iam:PassRole` permission that is required to 'pass' that role to a requested EC2 instance on start, see section *Permissions Required for Using Roles with Amazon EC2* within [Granting Applications that Run on Amazon EC2 Instances Access to AWS Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/role-usecase-ec2app.html) for details:

> To launch an instance with a role, the developer must have permission
>   to launch Amazon EC2 instances and permission to pass IAM roles.
>
> The following sample policy allows users to use the AWS Management
>   Console to launch an instance with a role. The policy allows a user to
>   pass any role and to perform all Amazon EC2 actions by specifying an
>   asterisk (*). The ListInstanceProfiles action allows users to view all
>   the roles that are available on the AWS account.
>
> **Example Policy that grants a user permission to launch an instance
>   with any role by using the Amazon EC2 console**
>
> ```
> {
>   "Version": "2012-10-17",   
>   "Statement": [{
>     "Effect": "Allow",
>     "Action": [
>       "iam:PassRole",
>       "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
>       "ec2:*"
>     ],
>     "Resource": "*"
>   }]
> }
> ```

The reason for requiring this indirection via the `PassRole` permission is the ability to *restrict which role a user can pass to an Amazon EC2 instance when the user is launching the instance*:

> This helps prevent the user from running applications that
>   have more permissions than the user has been granted—that is, from
>   being able to obtain elevated privileges. For example, imagine that
>   user Alice has permissions only to launch Amazon EC2 instances and to
>   work with Amazon S3 buckets, but the role she passes to an Amazon EC2
>   instance has permissions to work with IAM and DynamoDB. In that case,
>   Alice might be able to launch the instance, log into it, get temporary
>   security credentials, and then perform IAM or DynamoDB actions that
>   she's not authorized for.

You might want to read my answer to [How to specify an IAM role for an Amazon EC2 instance being launched via the AWS CLI?](https://serverfault.com/a/548083/10305) for a more elaborate explanation, which also links to Mike Pope's nice article about [Granting Permission to Launch EC2 Instances with IAM Roles (PassRole Permission)](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3M0IFB5XBOCQX/Granting-Permission-to-Launch-EC2-Instances-with-IAM-Roles-PassRole-Permission), which explains the subject matter from an AWS point of view.